# UNITY v.3 - BehaviorInterception using namespace matching

Tags: unity-container, aop, enterprise-library

How can I apply a behavior to all interface in a specific namespace?
I know how to apply a behavior to a concrete interface like IMyBlFacade,
but I don't want to do that for all interfaces separately, but in one shot.

Is implementing a ICallHandler obsolete when using custom IInterfaceBehaviors?
As I understand both build up a pipeline for interception.

What is the benefit of using ootb callhandlers and custom callhandlers over IInterfacebehaviors?

I don't want it to be like this:

```
unity.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>(
new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), 
new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), 
new InterceptionBehavior<OutputInterceptionBehavior>());
```

rather like this (pseudo code):

```
unity.addInterceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>()
.addMachingRule<namespace>("mynamespace")
.addBehaviors(...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is partly possible using Unity's RegistrationByConvention.
As far as I have understood, you can only do simple mappings.

For more complex mappings, for example using various InjectionMembers, you have to map them manually.

You have to inherit from RegistrationConvention to build your own convention implementation.

```
public class UnityRegistrationByConventions : RegistrationConvention
{

    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    List<string> _assemblyNameFilter;
    List<string> _namespaceFilterForClasses;

    public UnityRegistrationByConventions(IUnityContainer container, List<string> assemblyNameFilter = null, List<string> namespaceFilterForClasses = null)
    {
        _container = container;
        _assemblyNameFilter = assemblyNameFilter;
        _namespaceFilterForClasses = namespaceFilterForClasses;
    }

    public override Func<Type, IEnumerable<Type>> GetFromTypes()
    {
        return WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface;
    }

    public override Func<Type, IEnumerable<InjectionMember>> GetInjectionMembers()
    {
        return (t => new List<InjectionMember>(){
                new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), 
                new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingInterceptionBehavior>(),     // 1
                new InterceptionBehavior<ExceptionInterceptionBehavior>(),   // 2
                new InterceptionBehavior<CachingInterceptionBehavior>(),     // 3
                new InterceptionBehavior<ValidationInterceptionBehavior>()} as IEnumerable<InjectionMember>);
    }

    public override Func<Type, LifetimeManager> GetLifetimeManager()
    {
        return t => WithLifetime.Transient(t);
    }

    public override Func<Type, string> GetName()
    {
        return (type => (this._container.Registrations.Select(x => x.RegisteredType)
            .Any(r => type.GetInterfaces().Contains(r) == true) == true) ? WithName.TypeName(type) : WithName.Default(type));
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes()
    {

        var allAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => _assemblyNameFilter.Contains(a.FullName.Split(',')[0]));
        List<Type> allClasses = new List<Type>();


        foreach (var assembly in allAssemblies)
        {
            var classArray = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsPublic &&
                !t.IsAbstract &&
                t.IsClass == true &&
                _namespaceFilterForClasses.Contains(t.Namespace));
            if (classArray != null && classArray.Count() > 0)
                allClasses.AddRange(classArray);
        }

        return allClasses;
    }
}
```

and apply the convention like this

```
var rby = new UnityRegistrationByConventions(unityContainer, assFilter, classNamespaceFilter);
```